# Android Dynamic Edit Texts

Tags: android, performance

I have 85 settings items that I need to display on a view. I cannot use a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` because `EditTexts` are horrible. Doing the way I am doing causes a huge slow down. I do not want to make these manually. Any help is appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ssm_ll);
    List<Category> AllCats = (List<Category>) getArguments().getSerializable("Category");
    temp = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Category cg : AllCats) {
                LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoring_setting_template, null);
                TextView Catwording = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.sst_catwording);
                Catwording.setText("" + cg.getCatWording());
                temp.addView(tv);
            }
        }
    }).run();
    temp.addView(temp);
    ll.addView(temp);
}
```

Comment: What does RecyclerView or ListView have to do with EditText? Can you please clarify what your trying to do also, don't use onViewCreated like this...

Comment: If you use an EditText in a Recyclerview or Listview the tab order doesn't function properly along other general weirdness. A recyclerview  or listview would load properly. What is wrong with using onViewCreate like this. I believe you I just don't know.

Comment: You could use the ViewHolder implementation within an Adapter for a ListView, storing your EditText field values into a List and then using that List to repopulate your EditText fields within the Adapter's `getView()` method. If you need a full example of what I am talking about let me know and I can write a more complete answer.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Do you know if that will still have a problem with tab order for edittexts in a listview? The problem in the past. When you get to the visible end in the listview because the other ones don't exist until they are drawn it just ends. That is the main reason I didn't want to a listview or a recycler.

Comment: I am a bit confused what do you mean, sorry. What exactly do you mean by tab order?

Comment: If you set the imeOptions="actionNext" it should continue to the next element in the view. With a listview this will cause the last drawn edit text to be viewed as the last one and wrap to the top.Tab order isn't the right term but that would be what it is for a web form.  Does that make sense ?

Comment: Was going to comment but it was too long, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too Long for Comment, Not Sure if it Works, Just a Suggestion to Try**

I haven't tested this at all, but it was too long to suggest trying in a comment. If it doesn't work let me know and I will delete this as a possible answer (please keep from your negative votes again I am not certain of this as an answer).

Since an Adapter in a ListView is supposed to handle creating the next view that isn't seen, which allows smooth scrolling, you could possibly still manage this in a ListView (theoretically). You could programmatically set the id and handle the the next call like so within your Adapter's `getView()` :

```
editText.setId(position + 1);      // + 1 so your id is never 0
if(position < getCount() - 1)
    editText.setNextFocusDown(position + 2);     // the id of the next edit text
else
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION.DONE);
```

Theoretically, your ListView will always have built the next item in the list's view unless it is the last item in the list (which you can then set the ime options to done), not 100% on that though. Again, I am not sure if this works but it is obviously too much for a comment.

*while I am making a post*

For the content of each EditText you could do something like

```
private SparseArray<String> mEditTextInputs = new SparseArrayt<>();
```

then in `getView()`, make position parameter final and try

```
editText.setText(mEditTextInputs.get(position);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        mEditTextInputs.put(position, s.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best idea, but in order to do what you ask create a Layout and Populate a `ScrollView` with `EditText` so when you select next on keyboard it goes down one `EditText`:

Here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/lt-tibs1984/5d3e6a50f9d883026014

to go even further each time you do:

```
       int count = 0;

       for (String item : items) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDemo);
            editText.setText(item);
            // set a tag here to uniquely identify it later
            editText.setTag(count);
            mLinearLayout.addView(view);
            count++;
        }
```

Alternative loop:

```
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 25; i++) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDemo);
            editText.setText(items.get(i));
            // set a tag here to uniquely identify it later
            editText.setTag(i);
            mLinearLayout.addView(view);
        }
```